# Akka-http custom 404 page

Tags: akka-http

I'd like to create a custom 404 page in akka-http (high level DSL). This basically means:

1. Return a page from my static folder (e.g. resources/www/404.html)
2. Set the result code to ResultCodes.NOT_FOUND

What I tried so far:

1. getFromResource - I can return the entity, but I can't figure out how to override the HTTP result code for the response, so I can set it to '404'.
2. complete() - I can return the right code, but I need to read the html page in manually, and build the HttpResponse from ground up. It eventually works, but it's a bit cumbersome.

Am I missing something? Is there an easier way to return a page and customize the result code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static page can be returned as the `entity` of an [`HttpResponse`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.11/#akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpResponse).

Assuming you have some function of the form

```
def someFunctionThatCanFail() : Try[HttpResponse] = ???
```

You will want to use your static page in the event of a failure.  You'll first need to create a `Source` that is based on the static page:

```
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpEntity.Chunked

def createStaticSource(fileName : String) = 
  FileIO
    .fromPath(Paths get fileName)
    .map(ChunkStreamPart.apply)

def createChunkedSource(fileName : String) = 
  Chunked(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, createStaticSource(fileName))
```

This source can then be placed inside of a response:

```
def staticResponse = 
  HttpResponse(status = StatusCodes.NotFound,
               entity = createChunkedSource("resources/www/404.html"))
```

The only thing left to do is to either return the result of the function if it was valid or the static response in the case of a failure:

```
val route = 
  get {
    complete(someFunctionThatCanFail() getOrElse staticResponse)
  }
```

Comment: @WillIAm You are welcome.  I agree it's not as simple as a "one liner"  but I don't see how that would be possible.  Creating a 404 response with entity is the exact same action as creating a 400 response with entity.  There's enough divergence in the pattern that I don't think the library could improve the verbosity much.  I've updated the answer to make it more like a util library function, at least you only have to write it once...

Comment: Oops, I deleted my previous comment by mistake (but there wasn't anything important, just thanking and complaining that it wasn't very simple :). BTW, on your code I get a compilation error on line staticResponse = ... (expected Seq[HttpHeader], actual HttpEnttity.Chunked)

Comment: Thanks.The reason I said it needs to be easier is because not everyone uses Scala. Been trying to convert the above example to use the javadsl, and didn't get past the implementation of createChunkedSource

Comment: I am revisiting this answer (thanks again) for a new project. I am finding that the fromPath does not work while the application is packaged in a jar . Is that correct or do I have some other bug? If it's correct, what are my alternatives?

Comment: @WillIAm I have definitely used fromPath with external files after a jar packaging.  Maybe try bundling a small test file into the resources directory that gets packaged with the jar.  If that works then at least you've isolated the source of the problem...

Comment: Thanks. I think I figured out the problem that it is having trouble finding the ZipFileSystemProvider (FileSystemNotFoundException). So it's probably not related to your code directly.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Ramon's excellent answer, this works inside a jar file as well:

```
 def createChunkedSource(fileName : String): Chunked = {
    def createStaticSource(fileName : String) : Source[ChunkStreamPart, Any] = {
      val classLoader = getClass.getClassLoader
      StreamConverters.fromInputStream(() => classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName)).map(ChunkStreamPart.apply)
    }
    Chunked(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, createStaticSource(fileName))
  }
```